# selenium - assert existence of notifications

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a simple HTML5 login, which shows a notification if the login fails.

I'm using the Javascript Notification API for the notification from here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Furthermore, I want to test the existence of the notification in selenium.
I want to assert in selenium if such a notification is shown to the user. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You want to add more information, so that it will help people to understand what exactly you mean and related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not possible to handle notifications using Selenium yet. Follow this discussions: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1501 https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2259

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to deactivate the notification feature in chrome? I've tried this, but doesn't work:

var options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", "2");
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(options.toCapabilities()).build();

Comment: First - please format code also in comments. Second -  "Doesn't work" tells nothing (you got exception? running but notifications are still enabled?). I have no idea how to disable it, so if you cant find solution, you can start new thread.